# reactstrap Navbar not opining or collapsing when clicked

Tags: reactjs, navbar, reactstrap

I have Implemented the reactstrap navbar in react and it is working but the collapse button is not opening/closing

here is my code:

```
<Navbar color="light" expand="md" light>
    <NavbarBrand href="/">QIFF DASHBOARD</NavbarBrand>
    <NavbarToggler onClick={function noRefCheck() {}} />
    <Collapse navbar>
      <Nav navbar>{createLinks(routes)}</Nav>
    </Collapse>
    <NavbarText onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavbarText>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });

render() {
return (
<Navbar color="inverse" inverse toggleable>
          <NavbarToggler right onClick={this.toggle} />
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">Github</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
)}
```

`